# CakePhp 4 Error when a not logged out user wants to login again

Tags: cakephp

I use CakePhp 4 with Authentication and Authorization plugins. All works fine except for this scenarion :
Scenario :
A user launches her browser, then enter my app's URL and logins. All works fine.
Then, she opens a new tab on the browser and to visit a new different website.
Then she decides to close my app's tab whitout logout properly from my app.
Then she decides to reopen a new tab to return on my app and here an error is raised:

The request to `/` did not apply any authorization checks.

I think this error is due to the fact that the user did not logout when she closed the browser tab. It is a good thing that the user can't reopen the app for security reasons because we can't be sure the user is the same than the first user. I can't figure out how to manage this error

Could somebody help me ? Thank you.
Patrick

Comment: What controller and action is "/" mapped to in your application? Sounds like you're not doing any `$this->Authorization->authorize` call in that action function.

Comment: Thank you Greg for your answer. I changed the mapped route for "/" to "users" controller "login" action and the is no error when I execute the scenario. Before changing, "/" was mapped to "Pages" controller and "display" action in config/Route.php.